# Reporting capabilities on Chatter feed Item

Tags: chatter-feed-tracking

We have enabled chatter feed tracking on a child object in salesforce. the UI tracks the changes we did, but we need to see ways of doing reporting on such chatter feed changes from the child object.

Let me know of any suggestions.

Regards,
Manoj.

Answer (score 1):

This is possible by creating a Custom Report for Object Feeds, see the Summer '15 [release notes](http://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/summer15/release-notes/rn_chatter_reporting_dashboards_pkg.htm) for more details.

Comment: Thanks Alex. But are you sure we can report on exact value changes? the Summer'15 notes doesnt explcitly mention this. It talks about counts and type of users who were part of chatter feeds.

Comment: I've not used the reporting myself so I can't be sure. But have you considered [field history tracking](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=tracking_field_history.htm&language=en_US)? It records exactly what you say you're looking for and it's rare that Salesforce creates the same functionality twice, as a separate feature. If you could add both your requirements & reasons why field history tracking's not an option to your question, we can hopefully get it taken off hold..